How can Length of Bytes Written by Writer be Read
To generate a quality PDF document using the answer provided here, the length of written bytes should be calculated before the Writer is done since it should be the value before w.write("%%EOF\n").
How can the length of written bytes be read Eg. before line w.write("xref\n") in the answer?
EDIT
The following generates Test15.pdf with calculated xref length according to the answer below.
 private void createPdf15() {
    try {
        //Image image = Image.createImage("/Logo.jpg");
        Image image = Image.createImage("/android_logo.png");
        //Image image = Image.createImage("/ios_logo.png");

        //create a jpeg encoded image
        EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.createFromImage(image, true);
        byte[] imageData = encodedImage.getImageData();

        int imageWidth = encodedImage.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = encodedImage.getHeight();
        int imageLength = imageData.length;

        //create ByteArrayInputStream from image byte array
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);

        FileSystemStorage fss = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
        String pdfPath = fss.getAppHomePath() + "Test15.pdf";
        StreamCounter streamCount = new StreamCounter(fss.openOutputStream(pdfPath));
        try (Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(streamCount, "ISO-8859-1")) {
            w.write("%PDF-1.7\n");
            w.write("1 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>endobj\n");
            w.write("2 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Kids [3 0 R]/Count 1>>endobj\n");
            w.write("3 0 obj<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources 4 0 R/MediaBox [0 0 520 800]/Contents 6 0 R>>endobj\n");
            w.write("4 0 obj<</Font<</F1 5 0 R>>/XObject<</Im0 7 0 R>>>>endobj\n");
            w.write("5 0 obj<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/BaseFont/Helvetica>>endobj\n");
            w.write("6 0 obj<</Length 219>>stream\n");
            w.write("q\n");
            w.write("BT /F1 24 Tf 175 720 Td (Codename One)Tj ET\n");
            w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 100 700 Td (Using one codebase, build)Tj ET\n");
            w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 660 Td (Android apps)Tj ET\n");
            w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 640 Td (iOS apps)Tj ET\n");
            w.write("BT /F1 20 Tf 0 600 Td (UWP apps)Tj ET\n");
            w.write("q 50 0 0 50 4 540 cm /Im0 Do Q\n");
            w.write("Q\n");
            w.write("endstream\n");
            w.write("endobj\n");

            int bytesWritten = streamCount.getWritten();
            Log.p("1bytesWritten: " + bytesWritten); // Total1 = 0 -> Text1Length = 0

            w.write("7 0 obj<</Type/XObject/Subtype/Image/Width " + imageWidth + "/Height " + imageHeight + "/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/BitsPerComponent 8/Filter/DCTDecode/Length " + imageLength + ">>stream\n");

            //read the next byte of data from ByteArrayInputStream in int range 0 - 255
            int nextChar = byteArrayInputStream.read();
            while (nextChar > -1) {
                //convert int to char and add it to char array
                char[] charArray = {(char) nextChar};
                //write char array
                w.write(charArray);
                nextChar = byteArrayInputStream.read();
            }
            w.write("\nendstream\n");
            w.write("endobj\n");


            bytesWritten = streamCount.getWritten();
            Log.p("2bytesWritten: " + bytesWritten); //Total2 = 16384 -> Image1Length = 7732 Text2Length = 8652 ??

            w.write("xref\n");
            w.write("0 8\n");
            w.write("0000000000 65535 f \n");
            w.write("0000000009 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000052 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000102 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000197 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000255 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000316 00000 n \n");
            w.write("0000000609 00000 n \n");
            w.write("trailer\n");
            w.write("<</Size 9/Root 1 0 R>>\n");
            w.write("startxref\n");
            //w.write("133724\n");
            w.write(bytesWritten + "\n");
            w.write("%%EOF\n");

            w.flush();

            bytesWritten = streamCount.getWritten();
            Log.p("3bytesWritten: " + bytesWritten);//Total3 = 17466

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.p("Error " + e);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.p("Error " + e);
    }
}


Writer doesn't support that. Since the encoding you used is pretty simple (ISO-8859-1) you can probably calculate this yourself since it would be equivalent to the number of characters written.
But this is a more generic solution:
public class StreamCounter extends FilterOutputStream {
    private int written;
    public StreamCounter(OutputStream out) {
        super(out);
    }

    public int getWritten() {
        return written;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
        super.write(buffer, offset, length);
        written += length;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int oneByte) throws IOException {
        super.write(oneByte);
        written++;
    }
}

Then use it as such:
try {
   StreamCounter streamCount = new StreamCounter(fss.openOutputStream(pdfPath));
   try (Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(streamCount)) {
       // same code as before
       w.flush();
       int bytesWritten = streamCount.getWritten();
       // ...
   }
} catch(IOException err) {
    Log.e(e);
}


@KJ is the calculated length of xref in the generated Test15.pdf okay?

@KJ Notice that the filter is in the stream and not the writer. Bytes are written, it has no notion of characters. Only bytes.

@KJ I logged size of written bytes at different parts. Before image, I logged Log.p("1bytesWritten: " + bytesWritten); here value of bytesWritten = 0. After the image,  I logged Log.p("2bytesWritten: " + bytesWritten); value of bytesWritten = 16384. Since length of image bytes = 7732. I calculated length of text bytes as 16384  - 7732 = 8652. That is why I wondered if length of text bytes is really 8652 ??

After writer is done I logged Log.p("3bytesWritten: " + bytesWritten); value of bytesWritten = 17466

@KJ Did you invoke flush() like I did in the code?

@KJ flush() is invoked in my code sample above on the writer. It's a method of Java OutputStream and Writer classes. Since streams in Java can cache bytes and not move them down the chain it's possible that all bytes weren't written unless you invoke flush() explicitly.

Suggestion to add flush() before counting works since Log.p("1bytesWritten: " + bytesWritten); //bytesWritten = 751.

The next problem was that, the resulting 17466 bytes length exceeded the actual file size which is 8722 bytes = 8.7KB. This is because write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length) in StreamCounter doubles the previously read bytes. Eg. In this count log before line [EDT] 0:0:1,834 - 1bytesWritten: 1502 you can see that bytesWritten by write function with 1 parameter = 751. In the next line, bytesWritten by the write function with 3 parameter = 1502, meaning it was doubled.

The solution was to remove write function with 3 parameters in StreamCounter class and count bytes using the write function with 1 parameter ONLY. This resulted to this count log and this Test15.1.pdf.

@KJ I had missed to set size to 8. You are right, in Linux, image in  Test15.1 shows in Document Viewer but it doesn't show in Mozilla browser. It only shows after changing 6 0 obj<</Length 219>>stream to 6 0 obj<</Length 254>>stream and changing 0000000609 00000 to 0000000616 00000

How can length of object 6 (254) and 616 be calculated?

Can you please use values in this to explain?
